# Start Azure VM script from Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am building a Logic App to coordinate a sequence of jobs for large scale data processing.

One of the steps in this process involves running a shell script (and some Python code) on an Azure Ubuntu VM. The script takes approximately 2 hours to complete. I have to run this script on the VM. It would not migrate well to an Azure function.

What is the best way to have my Logic App kick off this script?

Comment: Hi Kevin, did you figure something out since? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I would look into:

1. Exposing a trigger to the scripts by http.
2. Create an Azure Automation script to start the VM and have the scripts run as a startup task on the VM.  Use the Logic App Automation Connector to trigger the Job.